# Is it possible to travel from Panama City to Medellin, Colombia by car/bus?

Tags: overland, colombia, panama, medellin, panama-city

I'm from Brazil and I'm planning to fly to Panama and then take a bus from Panama City to Medellin, is it possible?

Direct flights are so expensive!

Comment: The linked question should give you some idea of how to travel between Panama and Colombia without flying. But the gist of it is, that there's no road between Panama and Colombia (known as the [Darien Gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari%C3%A9n_Gap)) and thus it will be hard to take a bus.

Comment: There are no buses, because there are no roads!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, no.

There is no road connecting the two countries. Briefly and recently, a ferry ran between Panama and Colombia. However, it seems it is no longer available: [Their Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/ferryxpress) is empty, [their website](http://www.ferryxpress.com) is suspended. [Outdated information at Wikioverland](http://wikioverland.org/Panama_to_colombia_car_ferry_xpress) suggests the ferry didn't run for most of 2015 either.